# Omit rows where multiple columns contain NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to figure out how to build a query that omits rows where both columns of interest are `NULL`. If only one or the other is `NULL`, then I would like to include that data.

In this example table, I would like to have a query that includes everything except row 3.

```
ID      Col1        Col2
0       10.0        5.0
1       NULL        10.0
2       20.0        15.0
3       NULL        NULL
4       25.0        20.0
5       50.0        NULL
```

My thought would be to build a query as so:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE Col1 & Col2 IS NOT NULL
```

This however omits any row where either **Col1** or **Col2** contains a `NULL`, yielding:

```
ID      Col1        Col2
0       10.0        5.0
2       20.0        15.0
4       25.0        20.0
```

I want to include row 1 and 5.

If someone could point me in the right direction to form a `WHERE` clause that could perform such logic conditional to values across more than one column.

Thanks!

Comment: So if _This however omits any row where either Col1 or Col2 contains a NULL_ You obviously built a query and tested it. So **show us the real query**

Comment: `&` is a [bitwise operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/bit-functions.html), so does not do what you think here. If you put that in the select you will see why your query does not work. [Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e5ea78/1). Use `AND` or `OR` to combine predicates. This should do it for you: `WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL OR Col2 IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
;with cte as (
SELECT 0 AS ID, 10.0 AS Col1, 5.0 AS Col2 
UNION SELECT 1, NULL, 10.0
UNION SELECT 2, 20.0, 15.0 
UNION SELECT 3, NULL, NULL 
UNION SELECT 4, 25.0, 20.0 
UNION SELECT 5, 50.0, NULL 
) 
SELECT * FROM cte  
WHERE Col1 is not null
   or Col2 is not null
```

Comment: Thank you! This put me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot shorted the where clause like that as `&` is a bitwise and, so this should do what you are asking for

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL 
   OR Col2 IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: This does not work. If either **Col1** or **Col2** has ```NULL```, the row will be omitted.

Comment: Then all you need is to change AND to OR